# how to populate data of javascript object values in option of html select using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**javascript object** named countries.
Now this data i want to populate in HTML select

```
var countries = {
    India:"delhi",
    US:"Norway",
    UK:"London",
    id: 123752,
    allcountries : function(){return this.India +" "+ this.US + " " + this.UK + " "+this.id}
};
```

**HTML Code**

```
<select id="con">
    <option></option>
</select>
```

**I tried**

```
document.getElementById("con").innerHTML = countries.allcountries();

$('#con option').append(countries.India);
```

but it is not working can anyone help me to populate data using jquery/javascript in html select.

Comment: what is your expected output? because if this is your js object then you have to create new object and push the country's name and values in it, then you can loopin to populate.

Comment: Thank you guys all answers are correct.

Comment: all are voted up for best answers for jquery as well as javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
var countries = {
    India: "delhi",
    US: "Norway",
    UK: "London"
};

$('#con').html($.map(countries, function (val, key) {
    return '<option value="' + key + '">' + val + '</option>';
}).join(''));
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j5F5y/)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

HTML:-

```
<select id="con">
    <option></option>
</select>
```

Javascript:-

```
var countries = {
India:"delhi",
US:"Norway",
UK:"London",
id: 123752
};

$.each(countries, function (key, value) {
    $('#con').append($('<option/>', { 
        value: value,
        text : key 
    }));
});
```

**It will add capitals of Countries as values of options.**

Answer (score 1):

In native javascript, you may try the code below:

```
<script>
var countries = {
    India:"delhi",
    US:"Norway",
    UK:"London"
};
window.onload=function(){
    console.log(countries);

    var select = document.getElementById("con");
    var option;

    for (var key in countries) {
        option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = key;
        option.textContent = countries[key];
        select.appendChild(option);
    }
};
</script>

<select id="con">
    <option></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

What my suggestion is to have a blank `<select>` like this:

```
<select id="con"></select>
```

and update your function like this:

```
var countries = {
    India: "delhi",
    US: "Norway",
    UK: "London",
    id: 123752,
    allcountries: function () {
        return this.India + " " + this.US + " " + this.UK + " " + this.id
    },
    conToPopulate: function () { // make a new func to return an object
        var o = {}; // create an object
        o['India'] = this.India; // push the required keys and values
        o['US'] = this.US;
        o['UK'] = this.UK;
        return o; // now outputs : {India: "delhi", US: "Norway", UK: "London"}
    }
};
$(function () {
    $.each(countries.conToPopulate(), function (key, value) {
        $('#con').append($('<option/>', {
            value: value,
            text: key
        }));
    });
});
```

### [Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WYnQ3/)